# moving rows in lockstep and return mistake?

Tags: vba, excel

I have been looking at how to develop a macro that deals with two columns - one holding a code for marriage status and the other relationship status. For example:

1. SI    daughter
2. M     wife
3. M     husband
4. SI    son
5. D     mother
6. W     father
7. M     son
8. M     wife
9. SI    daughter
10. SI    husband

SI stands for single, D for divorced, M for married, W for widowed, and so on.

The purpose of the macro is to test for mistakes, where a daughter or son cannot be other than single, and do that for about 1000 rows, and do so by evaluating the two adjacent cells in every row and returning the row that matches the criteria for a mistake. The mistakes above are that SI cannot be a Husband and M cannot be a Son.

For a single row, the following will do the job:

```
 If Cells(2, 1).Value = "M" And Cells(2, 2).Value = "son" Then
        MsgBox "You've found a mistake"
      else
        MsgBox "Keep checking"
    End If
```

Doing the above for 1000 rows is impractical, so for the purpose of evaluating them, I came up with the following, but it does not work quite to specification:

```
Sub attempt9()

Dim i As Integer

Dim cell As Range
Dim cell2 As Range
Dim y As Range
Dim z As Range

Set y = Range("A1:A10")
Set z = Range("B1:B10")

For i = 1 To 10

    For Each cell In y
        cell.Offset(i, 0).Select
        For Each cell2 In z
            cell2.Offset(i, 0).Select
            If cell.Offset(i, 0).Value = "M" And cell2.Offset(i, 0).Value = "husband" Then
                Range("D1") = cell.Address & ", " & cell2.Address
            End If
        Next cell2
    Next cell
    Exit For
Next i


End Sub
```

The main issue I'm facing is how to get the loop to move the two adjacent cells row by row in lockstep and return the row or addresses of the erroneous cells. I've programmed the selections to move at the same iteration in both columns with every loop cycle, and so far, it will return the address of the cell with a value "M" in the first column, and the value of a cell with the value "husband" in the second column, but the rows will not match - and there is a strict IF AND condition for the purpose.

Comment: Why do you have a `exit for` at the end of your first loop?

Comment: Because the loop crashed Excel a couple of times when it went 1000 times around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, you just need to use the loop variable to reference the row number and you can use a `Select Case` block to test all the error situations:

```
Dim error As Boolean

For i = 1 To 10
    Select Case True
        Case Cells(i, 1).Value = "M" And Cells(i, 2).Value = "son": error = True
        Case Cells(i, 1).Value = "M" And Cells(i, 2).Value = "daughter": error = True
        Case Cells(i, 1).Value = "SI" And Cells(i, 2).Value = "husband": error = True
        '// repeat above for all error cases
        Case Else: error = False
    End Select

    If error Then
        MsgBox "You've found a mistake at row " & i
        Exit For '// To stop the code and fix the error
    End If
Next

MsgBox "Checking complete!"
```

Comment: Thank you much. It seems I was overthinking this thing, and looking at using the Select Case in place of the If-And statement in that loop.

Comment: No worries, don't forget to mark as the answer if it helped :)

Comment: Done and done. At the risk of spamming, thanks again!